# EF Core one-to-many self-relation in a single table

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0, c#-10.0

In case of following model class:

```
public sealed class Foo
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

Is that possible to use something like:

```
public sealed class FooEntityTypeConfiuration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Foo> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("foos");

        builder.HasKey(_ => _.Id);

        builder
            .HasOne()
            .WithMany(_ => _.Foos)
            .HasForeignKey(_ => _.Id)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
            .IsRequired(true);
    }
}
```

To create one-to-many self-relation in a ***single*** postgresql table with EF Core? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So-o-o... The answer was to:

1. Change a model.

```
public sealed class Foo
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid? ParentFooId { get; set; }

    public Foo ParentFoo { get; set; }

    public List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

2. Change `IEntityTypeConfiguration`.

```
public sealed class FooEntityTypeConfiuration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Foo> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("foos");

        builder.HasKey(_ => _.Id);

        builder
            .HasOne(_ => _.ParentFoo)
            .WithMany(_ => _.Foos)
            .HasForeignKey(_ => _.ParentFooId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
            .IsRequired(false);
        builder.HasIndex(_ => _.ParentFooId);
    }
}
```

And in migration you will get something like this.

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "foos",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: false),
        ParentFooId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: true)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_foos", x => x.Id);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_foos_foos_ParentFooId",
            column: x => x.ParentFooId,
            principalTable: "foos",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });

migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_foos_ParentFooId",
    table: "foos",
    column: "ParentFooId");
```